# Max fuction in Postgres does not give the max value

Tags: postgresql

I am writing a simple `SQL` query to get the latest record from every customer and to get the `max` of device_count if there are multiple records for a customer with same timestamp. However, the `max` function doesn't seem to take the `max` value though. Any help would be appreciated.
My `SQL` query -

```
select sub.customerid, max(sub.device_count) from(
SELECT customerid, device_count,
    RANK() OVER
    (
           PARTITION by customerid
           ORDER BY date_time desc
    ) AS rownum
    FROM tableA) sub 
WHERE rownum = 1
group by 1
```

Sample data:

| customerid | device_count | date_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3573 | 2021-07-26 02:15:09-05:00 |
| A | 4 | 2021-07-26 02:15:13-05:00 |
| A | 16988 | 2021-07-26 02:15:13-05:00 |
| A | 20696 | 2021-07-26 02:15:13-05:00 |
| A | 24655 | 2021-07-26 02:15:13-05:00 |

Desired Output should be to get the row with max device_count which is 24655 but I get 16988 as the output.

Comment: what relationship is between TableA and TableB

Answer (score 1):

try to :

1. sort your table using `ORDER BY customerid,device_count`
2. Then apply the [LAST_VALUE(device_count)](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-last_value-function/#:%7E:text=Introduction%20to%20PostgreSQL%20LAST_VALUE(),DESC%5D%2C%20...%20) window function aver the `customerid` partition.

Apply `LAST_VALUE()` to find the latest `device_count` (since it's sorted ascending, the last device_count value is the max).

Answer (score 0):

You need to put device_count into the window function's order by and take out the aggregation:

```
select sub.customerid, device_count from(
SELECT customerid, device_count,
    RANK() OVER
    (
           PARTITION by customerid
           ORDER BY date_time desc, device_count desc
    ) AS rownum
    FROM tableA) sub where rownum=1;
```

But if the top row for a customerid has ties (in both date_time and device_count fields) it will return all such ties.  So better to replace RANK() with ROW_NUMBER().